# Javascript modification query

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, filter

I'm hoping someone can help me out with a little question.

I have the following code to change combo box entries based on what is selected in the previous box.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Representation of AJAX</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function update(str)
   {
   var xmlhttp;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }    

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","demo.php?opt="+str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <select id="optionA" onchange="update(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <select id="data">
    <option>Select an Option...</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And

```
<?php
  $opt = $_GET['opt'];

  switch($opt)
  {
    case 0:
    default:
      echo '
            <option>Select an Option...</option>
           ';
        break;
    case 1:
    echo '
        <option value="opt1_1">Option1_Test1</option>
        <option value="opt1_2">Option1_Test2</option>
        <option value="opt1_3">Option1_Test3</option>
       ';
        break;
    case 2:
    echo '
        <option value="opt2_1">Option2_Test1</option>
        <option value="opt2_2">Option2_Test2</option>
        <option value="opt2_3">Option2_Test3</option>
       ';
    break;
  }
 ?>
```

I'm not massively conversant with Javascript so was wondering if it were possible to modify the javascript (the second chunk of code I can deal with myself I think) to do what is described below.

Box 1 contains a row of images, serving as links, when one is clicked, a second box below these images is populated with more image links based on the selection from box 1 (information is grabbed from a database).

I imagine from my limited understanding that I should be able to modify the 'onchange' js event to an onclick or whatever the equivalent is (can't remember off the top of my head) event inside an 'img' tag, or an 'a href' tag, again can't remember which right now.

Hopefully someone will understand what I'm trying to do and make sense of it all :)

Thanks
TheMightySpud

Comment: I'm not sure I was totally clear on what I was looking for, it's a little confusing to explain, and I can't post images yet.  But here is a link to an image that may explain it better.  http://www.themightyspud.co.uk/SearchIdea.png

Comment: I only need help with the first two boxes, everything else I can work out for myself I think :)

Comment: Ah no.  Please ignore all of the selects, the code with the selects is what I'm using as a starting point.  Like you saw, it works fine.  The goal is to have no selects, just a row of thumbnail images, one for each option.  And when the user clicks one of the images, the next box down becomes populated with thumbnails representing the next 'level' of options down.

Comment: Huh?  I really don't understand what you mean.  I already have all my layout sorted out via css, it's just the 'interactivity' that I'm struggling with. :-/

Comment: Just posted some code, not sure if this is what you want. Try it and let me know. The next step will be to change the PHP code to return another table with images (instead of options of a select).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what you might want, it's some images linked to the ajax call. Replace next code by your first code and run it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Representation of AJAX</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function update(str)
   {
   var xmlhttp;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }    

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","demo.php?opt="+str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://bestinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Beautiful-nature-26-825x510.jpg"
             onclick="update(1)" width="100" height="100"/>
       </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://bestinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/121nature.jpg"
             onclick="update(2)" width="100" height="100"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://bestinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Natural-Wallpaper-10.jpg"
             onclick="update(3)" width="100" height="100"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <select id="data">
    <option>Select an Option...</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh great thanks, I understand what you mean now. :)  I think I've actually managed it using a <button> tag for each of the images.  Something I need to test a little bit 'in situ' but I'm close.  it's pretty close to what you have, just using CSS instead of a table :) Thanks for the help though :)